# Return signed values while using ctypes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, gcc, shared-libraries, ctypes

I have written a function in C as follows:

```
long long signed_multiplication(long long multiplicand, long long multiplier)
{
   long long product=0;
   product=multiplicand * multiplier;
   return(product);
}
```

In Python , I call the above function as follows:

```
c_lib = ctypes.CDLL(libname)
c_lib.signed_multiplication.argtypes = (ctypes.c_longlong,ctypes.c_longlong)
c_lib.signed_multiplication.restype =  (ctypes.c_longlong)

#test mutliplication
ret_value1 = c_lib.signed_multiplication(2,7) #correct result: 14
ret_value2 = c_lib.signed_multiplication(-2,-7) #correct result: 14
ret_value3 = c_lib.signed_multiplication(-2,7) # **Wrong result: 65522**
ret_value4 = c_lib.signed_multiplication(2,-7) # **Wrong result: 65522**
```

As seen, Python is unable to interpret the correct signed value of `ret_value3` and `ret_value4`, instead interpreting it as an unsigned value. What could be possible error here?

Comment: Are you sure this is the *exact* code?   Because this works (adding `import ctypes` anyway).  Make sure to make a [mcve].  65522 is the 16-bit truncated `unsigned short` result of the 2s complement -14 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF2 assuming `long long` is 64-bit and truncated to 0xFFF2).  The `ctypes` default return value is `int` not `unsigned short` so this code can't produce that result, at least with my compiler.  Are you running on a 16-bit compiler?

Comment: Thank you. This was solved!